# How to mock built-in operators

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I need to mock built-in operators like `unlink` and `rename` as part of a test suite. I can't get this to work using [`Test::MockObject`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockObject)

```
>> my $mock = Test::MockObject->new();
>> $mock->mock('unlink', sub { print "Mocked!\n"; });
>> unlink "foo";
0
```

Is it possible to mock built-in functions like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [overriding core functions](https://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html#OVERRIDING-CORE-FUNCTIONS):

> To override a Perl built-in routine with your own version, you need to import it at compile-time. This can be conveniently achieved with the [subs](https://metacpan.org/pod/subs) pragma. This will affect only the package in which you've imported the said subroutine:
>
> ```
>    use subs 'chdir';
>     sub chdir { ... }
>     chdir $somewhere;
> ```
>
> To override a built-in globally (that is, in all namespaces), you need to import your function into the `CORE::GLOBAL` pseudo-namespace at compile time:
>
> ```
>     BEGIN {
>         *CORE::GLOBAL::hex = sub {
>             # ... your code here
>         };
>     }
> ```
>
> The new routine will be called whenever a built-in function is called without a qualifying package:
>
> ```
>    print hex("0x50"),"\n";            # prints 1
> ```
>
> In both cases, if you want access to the original, unaltered routine, use the `CORE::` prefix:
>
> ```
>    print CORE::hex("0x50"),"\n";      # prints 80
> ```

See also [the relevant section in `perldoc perlsub`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions):

> When you override a built-in, your replacement should be consistent (if possible) with the built-in native syntax. You can achieve this by using a suitable prototype. To get the prototype of an overridable built-in, use the prototype function with an argument of "`CORE::builtin_name`" (see `prototype`).
>
> Note however that some built-ins can't have their syntax expressed by a prototype (such as system or chomp). If you override them you won't be able to fully mimic their original syntax.
>
> The built-ins `do`, `require` and `glob can` also be overridden, but due to special magic, their original syntax is preserved, and you don't have to define a prototype for their replacements. (You can't override the `do BLOCK` syntax, though).
>
> `require` has special additional dark magic: if you invoke your `require` replacement as `require Foo::Bar`, it will actually receive the argument `"Foo/Bar.pm"` in `@_`. See `require`.
>
> And, as you'll have noticed from the previous example, if you override `glob`, the `<*>` glob operator is overridden as well.
>
> In a similar fashion, overriding the `readline` function also overrides the equivalent I/O operator `<FILEHANDLE>`. Also, overriding `readpipe` also overrides the operators `` and `qx//`.
>
> Finally, some built-ins (e.g. `exists` or `grep`) can't be overridden.

Comment: Perfect! Is it possible to later unmock the function?

Comment: Surely `use subs 'chdir'` is identical to declaring it with `sub chdir;`, and neither are necessary if the definition comes before the call? That recommendation seems to be separate from the main point.

Comment: Note "*[using subs] will affect only the package in which you've imported the said subroutine*" ... If you want something else, show your code.

Comment: *"Is it possible to later unmock the function?"* I don't see why you would want to within a test program, but you would have to write `*chdir = \&CORE::chdir`.

Comment: @Borodin Docs say *conveniently* ... So, my guess is that the author, like me, doesn't like a bunch of `sub foo`, `sub blarf;` etc statements sprinkled around the code.

Comment: @Borodin I need to mock `rename` and `unlink` for my test file, but there are many files that will run in the same runtime.  I want `rename` and `unlink` when called from the functions that I am testing, to be mocked, but I don't want to mock them for other functions.  The solution may end up being to just abstract the calls out to subroutines and mock the subroutines.

Comment: Re "*Perfect! Is it possible to later unmock the function?*", It's best not to unhook. Instead, use a flag. `sub { if ($mock_active) { ... } else { CORE::chdir(...); }`

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Except for this case, where you're redefining something for which perl already has a definition, I think `use subs` should be considered to be archaic together with `use vars`. Perl's compiler treats a call to an undefined subroutine as a declaration and assumes that it is unprototyped. Even here I think an awkward list of `sub chdir`, `sub unlink` etc. would be useful to emphasize that these *core* operators are being overridden.

Comment: *"I don't want to mock [`rename` and `unlink`] for other functions"* Then the best way would be to localise the definitions with either `local` or different namespaces. Hacking typeglobs should be reserved for tested module code. I disagree with the idea of using a flag; that is very old-fashioned and unnecessarily pollutes the code.

Comment: @Borodin Actually, declaring with `sub unlink;` actually results in *Ambiguous call resolved as `CORE::unlink()`, qualify as such or use `&`* whereas `use subs 'unlink` doesn't.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Thank you. That's odd, and I would consider it to be a bug. Can you think why I shouldn't write it up?

Comment: @Borodin I can't but that might reflect a lack of imagination on my part. After all, all `subs` is doing is `*{"${callpack}::$sym"} = \&{"${callpack}::$sym"};`

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Likewise, but that's awful! It's always a shame when you must find a spanner (wrench) before you can drive your car. I'm surprised that `sub $sym` does something different, except that the variable wouldn't be expanded.