How can I mock Perl's unlink function?
I want to mock Perl's unlink to test that my code deletes the right files. Based on this question and its answers and this other question and its answers, I tried:
use strict;
use warnings;
use subs 'unlink';
  
sub mock_unlink {
    use Data::Printer; p @_;
    return;
}     

BEGIN {
    no warnings qw/redefine/;
    *CORE::GLOBAL::unlink = \mock_unlink;
    # *unlink = \mock_unlink;
    use warnings;
}
          
unlink "some file";

But when I run this, my mocked function does get called, but the list of arguments is empty. I also get a warning that unlink is undefined.
$ perl mcve.pl
[]
Undefined subroutine &main::unlink called at mcve.pl line 17.

I expected it to print
["some file"]

I've tried the commented out line *unlink = \mock_unlink;  instead, but that didn't change anything.
How do I need to mock unlink to check what files my code tries to delete?

Based on zdim's answer, I've tried:
package FooTest;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::unlink = sub {
        say "unlinking @_"; 
    };  
}   

Foo::unl('a', 'b', 'c');
1;

package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub unl {
    unlink @_;
}

1;

and a Foo.pm like here:
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub unl {
    unlink @_;
}
    
1;

with this test case
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

my @unlinked;
    
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::unlink = sub {
        push @unlinked, @_;
    }
}

use Foo;
Foo::unl("some file");
is_deeply(\@unlinked, ["some file"]);
done_testing();

These work as expected, but if I move the use Foo; before the BEGIN block, it does not call the mocked unlink. Why is that happening and do I just need to make sure my imports and BEGINs are in the right order, or is there more to it?

Need \&func_name (not \func_name) ... is that a typo in the question? Then, why that use subs 'unlink';?  Remove that statement.  It should work then

@zdim My bad, it was from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807612/how-to-mock-built-in-operators I've added it to the question

OK, I see -- in that case, the sub in that example (chdir in current namespace) turns out ambiguous so it need be pre-declared.  If it is direclty overridden in CORE::GLOBAL then there is no need.  Unless you really mean to use it before you declare it.

(In the comment above: "Unless you really mean to use it before you ..."  -- define it, I meant.)

As for discussion and examples added as the last part of the question -- "These work as expected, but if I move the use Foo; before the BEGIN block, it does not call the mocked unlink."  -- in that case Foo is compiled (and executed) before that "mocking" is ever seen by the compiler, as use... goes in the compilation (BEGIN) phase.  So yes, the order matters in such a case.

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

#use subs 'unlink';       # doesn't work
#use subs 'mock_unlink';  # this would but do you need it?

sub mock_unlink {
    say "Unlink: @_";
    return;
}

BEGIN {
    no warnings qw/redefine/;
    *CORE::GLOBAL::unlink = \&mock_unlink;
    #use warnings;  # no need, `no warnings` is scoped to this block
}

unlink "some file";

Notes

Need \&subname in order to get a reference to a named sub (not \subname)

The use subs pragma predeclares the named subs so one can use them without parenthesis even before they are defined.  This would work for the new name (mock_unlink) -- but which isn't even intended to be used directly; why bother

Why does it not work with use subs unlink;? ... I don't know. Apparently, pre-declaring  the sub to be replaced with a differently named one messes with the process.† Will update when I find out

The use warnings/no warnings are lexical -- the effect expires once the scope is exited.  So you don't need to re-enable warnings explicitly (but it is not an error either).

The return; in the sub returns undef (scalar context) or an empty list (list context).  This mostly indicates a failure of some sort, and it is thus in principle consistent with what unlink returns if it fails to delete ("false").
This doesn't exactly mimic unlink though, and which also sets $! (see docs).  If you want to mock it more tightly consider a bit more.‡
Leaving a return out altogether returns the return value from the last statement that has a return, in this case the say that returns true if successful.   I find that reasonable as well since this is a test.



†  According to ikegami's comments,

That would cause uses of unlink to compile into calls to the unlink sub instead of invocations of the unlink operator.

‡  From ikegami's comment,
use Errno qw(ENOENT);

sub mock_unlink { 
    say "Unlink: @_";

    $! = ENOENT; 
    return !!0;
}

Here !!0 produce a canonical false value, in scalar context either an empty string (string context) or a 0 (numerical context), and in a list context an empty list.

Thanks a bunch! The warnings and return were from the bigger context in my test suite, I forgot to remove them.

@Robert Ah, OK; it crossed my mind that that could be the reason.


use subs 'mock_unlink'; is useless. There isn't even any call to mock_unlink.



Re "Why does it not work with use subs unlink;?", That would cause uses of unlink to compile into calls to the unlink sub instead of invocations of the unlink operator. In other words, use *CORE::GLOBAL::unlink = \&mock_unlink; sub mock_unlink { ... } -or- use subs qw( unlink ); sub unlink { ... }. (Probably the former, so you can affect another file.)



Re "The return; in the sub returns undef.", Not quite. While it returns undef in scalar context, it returns nothing in list context.  /// 4) Re "and it is what unlink returns if it fails to delete.", Is it? The docs say it returns false and sets $!. Returning use Errno qw( ENOENT ); $! = ENOENT; return !!0; would be more accurate.


@ikegami  Thank you for comments, edited inaccuracies.  I still don't exactly understand the sub-vs-operator difference in Perl (as I told you before) thus I don't get why a (pre-)compiled sub, and not an operator, makes the replacement fail in this case.  (If I understood your comment.)

Sorry, I have claimed victory too early. My mcve works when everything is in one file and the test goes before the actual code under test. If it's in different files, my *CORE::GLOBAL::unlink = ... in the BEGIN block doesn't have an effect and the original unlink gets called. (I've added the code to the question.) @ikegami you mentioned "affect other files", can you clarify how this exactly needs to be set up?

@Robert "I  have claimed victory too early..." -- alright, will look into it.  Should still work

@Robert OK, I see now -- "do I ... need to make sure my imports and BEGINs are in the right order" -- Well, yes, if things are getting imported (use-ed, so processed in compilation phase) and other things are defined in BEGIN blocks (compilation phase) -- that may conflict/interfere with each other than the order does matter.  Now, this is in principle clearly undesirable as it is one more subtle thing that has to be right.  But what you present I think just has to be handled in the right order.

@Robert Another thing: in your new examples you are overriding unlink itself (same name!) while previously you were defining another function (mock_unlink) and then using that to override -- and these two approaches differ slightly and subtly, because there's yet another function definition which need happen in between.  Just something to keep in mind.

@zdim Oh, I didn't think this would make a difference.
